# minimal diameter of full preimage of torus

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Given a set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A\cap (x+\mathbb{Z}^n)\ne \emptyset$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$  (that is, $p(A)=\mathbb{T}^n$ for the projection $p:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{T}^n=\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$). Is it true that supremum of Eucledian distances between points of $A$ is not less then $\sqrt{n}$? (equality holds for the unit cube)

Or maybe even two points with $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ with $|x_i-y_i|\geq 1-\epsilon$ for each coordinate?

It is not hard to check both claims for $n=2$, but already for $n=3$ I do not know.

Comment: A small correction, you should put "for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$" in the first line. Also, are you assuming that $A$ is closed? Otherwise, the second question is false even with $n=1$. 

Comment: Remark:  $\sqrt{n}/2$ is easy, by simply taking both $x = (0,0,\ldots,0)$ and $x = (\frac12,\frac12,\ldots,\frac12)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second claim is false for $n=3$. Choose $\varepsilon$ small and $\delta\ll\varepsilon$. Let $A$ be the set of all points $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3$ satisfying the following  inequalities:
$$
\begin{cases}
 -1.5+\varepsilon+\delta &\le x+y+z &\le 1.5+\varepsilon \\
 -1.5+\delta &\le x+y-z &\le 1.5 \\
 -1.5+\delta &\le x-y+z &\le 1.5 \\
 -1.5+\delta &\le -x+y+z &\le 1.5 \\
\end{cases}
$$
The integer translates of this set cover the space, but its $\ell_1$-diameter is no greater than $3-\delta$.

**Added.** The first claim is false too. In the above example, fix $\delta=\varepsilon/10$ and add the inequality 
$$\max\{|x|,|y|,|z|\}\le 0.5+10\varepsilon$$
to the system.