# Lattice-point-free body diameter

Tags: reference-request, discrete-geometry

The following interesting problem was asked at [Aops](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u738252h2922192p26122750) and I wonder if it was based on some research paper:

> Let $K$ be a convex body in $\mathbb R^2$, such that the diameter of $K$ is less than $\sqrt2$.
> Prove that there is a lattice-point-free translation of $K$.

Is the 'convex condition' necessary?
Can this problem be generalized to $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Convexity is not necessary. This question was discussed here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/42774/4312

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For higher dimension, this does not hold, see the answer by Sergei Ivanov [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/42774/4312).

For dimension 2, in the closed set $K$ without lattice-point free translate (in other words, such that $K$ has a point in every translate $\mathbb{Z}^2+c$ of the lattice) we may even find two points for which both coordinates differ at least by 1. This may be proved as follows. Fix real $a\in [0,1]$ and consider the union of vertical lines $V_a:=\{(x, y) \colon x-a\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. In this set $V_a$, the ordinates take all values modulo 1, thus there exist two points $p_a, q_a\in V_a$ with ordinates differing at least by 1. If they have different abscissas, that's what we need. So, these $p_a, q_a$ have equal abscissa $v_a$, congruent to $a$ modulo 1. Therefore there exist two values $a, b$ for which $|v_a-v_b|$ is more than 1 or arbitrarily close to 1. Between points $p_a, q_a, p_b, q_b$ let $p_a$ be the lowest, then $p_a$ and the highest of $q_a, q_b$ is (almost) necessary pair of points.